# Should the [migrated-questions] tag be merged with the [migration] tag?

Tags: discussion, meta, migration, retag-request, migrated-questions

Right now, there are two tags on MSE that are broadly about migration (i.e. migrating a question from one site to another):

- The [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) tag is currently on 1,265 questions (not including this one). Its tag guidance simply describes what migration is. (It currently has 3 synonyms: [move-to-other-site](/questions/tagged/move-to-other-site), [question-migration](/questions/tagged/question-migration), and [moving-questions](/questions/tagged/moving-questions).)
- Meanwhile, the [migrated-questions](/questions/tagged/migrated-questions) tag is currently on 196 questions (not including this one). Its tag guidance also simply describes how migration works.

Both the [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) and [migrated-questions](/questions/tagged/migrated-questions) tags appear to be about the same thing, and seem to be used in the same way.

Should these tags be merged?
If so, what should remain as the final tag name – [migration](/questions/tagged/migration)? (And should the other tag be added as a synonym of it?)

---

(**Note**: There are a few other migration-related tags: [migration-rejection](/questions/tagged/migration-rejection), [migration-path-request](/questions/tagged/migration-path-request), and [migration-block](/questions/tagged/migration-block). However, those tags are out of scope for this question, since they're about specific things related to migration, not just about migration in general.)

Comment: Arguably it's the other way around: the [tag:migration] tag should be split up because it's too broad, not merged into a currently existing that that has a well-defined area. If the tags are misused, retag them. Don't make it worse.

Comment: @Mast: I assume your "other way around" comment is regarding the parenthetical at the end of my post? If you feel that there shouldn't be *any* tag about migration in general, you're welcome to post an answer recommending that all posts with those tags be retagged (in whatever way you suggest)... I only added that note to clarify that this post is for discussing what to do with the [migration] and [migrated-question] tags, not for discussing whether or not *other* tags should be merged into either of these two tags.

Comment: It's partly about the parenthetical, but even if we leave those out of scope: merging an overly big tag with a properly defined tag is exactly what shouldn't happen. There should be tags about migration, it's an important mechanism of the site that easily leads to confusion so there *must* be some tag(s) for it. Just don't throw it all on one heap. Tags should be a bit specific or they won't narrow it down when searching/filtering on them. If tags are wrongly applied, fix the tags on the questions. Not this. Does that clear it up?

Comment: @Mast: Ah, I see what you mean. In that case, you're also welcome to post an answer indicating that one of these tags (I assume [migrated-questions]) is a "properly-defined tag", in which case it's *not* the same as the other ("overly big") tag – and thus shouldn't be merged. (...I'm just not sure that [migrated-questions] *is* clearly defined in a way that distinguishes its scope, either in its tag wiki or based on the questions it's being used on. I'm open to hearing counterarguments – but please post it as an answer instead of a comment.)